# Change name of default contextual ribbon in access 2010

Tags: ms-access

Maybe its just an simple answer... 
Can you please tell me how can i rename this ?

[image: screenshot]

The xml code:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
<ribbon startFromScratch="false">
   <tabs>
     <tab id="MyTab1" label="MyTab1">
        <group id="MyGroup1" label="My Group1">
           <labelControl id="myLabel1" label="Sample:"/>
           <labelControl id="myLabel2" label="Demo"/>
        </group>
     </tab>
  </tabs>
<contextualTabs>
  <tabSet idMso="TabSetFormReportExtensibility">
    <tab id="tabContextual" label="My Contextual Tab">
      <group id="MyContextualGroup" label="My Group in Contextual Tab">
        <labelControl id="myLabel1a" label="Sample:"/>
        <button id="btnDemo" size="large" label="Demo"/>
      </group>
    </tab>
  </tabSet>
</contextualTabs>
```

Thanks for any help !!

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue isn't with changing the label.  I think that the `XML` itself is just broken so there is some remnant tab from before that is just staying there. You are missing the closing tags of your `<customUI>` and your `<ribbon>`.

So it should be:

```xml
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
<ribbon startFromScratch="false">
   <tabs>
     <tab id="MyTab1" label="MyTab1">
        <group id="MyGroup1" label="My Group1">
           <labelControl id="myLabel1" label="Sample:"/>
           <labelControl id="myLabel2" label="Demo"/>
        </group>
     </tab>
  </tabs>
 <contextualTabs>
  <tabSet idMso="TabSetFormReportExtensibility">
    <tab id="tabContextual" label="My Contextual Tab">
      <group id="MyContextualGroup" label="My Group in Contextual Tab">
        <labelControl id="myLabel1a" label="Sample:"/>
        <button id="btnDemo" size="large" label="Demo"/>
      </group>
    </tab>
  </tabSet>
 </contextualTabs>
</ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Once I made these changes your `XML` work perfectly. If by some chance you just accidentally didn't past the two last lines of your `XML` just know that your code isn't the issue.  You might just be stuck on some past attempt at making a custom tab.